# URL rewriting with PHP .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

So basically I got this URL that looks like this on my php website and i have no acces httpd.conf or i dnt know how to use it i just want to do this with .htaccess:

> http://www.example.com/full.php?id=57

How would I go about converting that URL to

> http://www.example.com/full/57

i have already tried on .htaccess

> **RewriteEngine** on
>   **RewriteRule** ^/full/([0-9]+)$ /full.php?id=$1

plz provide me a complete working code for this to use in .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_END} !^1$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_-]+)\.php$ $1/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_END} !^1$
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_-]+)\.php$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_-]+)/(.+)$ $1.php?id=$2 [E=END:1,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z_-]+)$ $1.php [E=END:1,L]
```

Comment: Remove what is into your htaccess and put my code only. Also, "not working" is not clear. What happened ?

Comment: Please provide more details ! What is not working ? Which url did you try to access ? What was the result (404 error, ...) ?

Comment: ok here is the url (http://eparyatan.com/full.php?id=57)

the rewrite is nt working

Comment: My code does actually work... See: http://eparyatan.com/full/57 You also have to add `<base href="http://eparyatan.com/" />` in your pages right after `<head>` html tag to fix css, images & js well known issues

Comment: and here is phpinfo() page if incase there is smthng mod rewrite enabled/disabled issue?  
http://eparyatan.com/phpinfo.php

Comment: yea it's working bt when i go to http://eparyatan.com/full.php?id=57 it wont convert to http://eparyatan.com/full/57. i want it actually

Comment: THank You very much :) it's working now... i also want http://eparyatan.com/view.php?id=समाचार to 
http://eparyatan.com/view/समाचार in full.php there was dynamic id(integer) and now in view there is dynamic id(unicode variable)

Comment: Well i edited my answer. It's the same code, but more generic

Comment: it's nt working on http://www.eparyatan.com/view.php?id=समाचार or http://eparyatan.com/view.php?id=गन्तब्य

Comment: now it's working bt in url unicode is nt rendering before there was http://www.eparyatan.com/view.php?id=[unicode_text] now http://www.eparyatan.com/view/%25E0%25A4%25B8%25E0%25A4%25AE%25E0%25A4%25BE%25E0%25A4%259A%25E0%25A4%25BE%25E0%25A4%25B0

Comment: This is unicode encoding. If you tested with http://eparyatan.com/view/गन्तब्य you can see it is the same as http://eparyatan.com/view/%25E0%25A4%2597%25E0%25A4%25A8%25E0%25A5%258D%25E0%25A4%25A4%25E0%25A4%25AC%25E0%25A5%258D%25E0%25A4%25AF

Comment: ok, no problem with that, 1 more... http://www.eparyatan.com/index.php or http://www.eparyatan.com/about.php to http://www.eparyatan.com/index or http://www.eparyatan.com/about will you plz

Comment: See my edited answer. I stop here because it is moving away from the original question

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$1.php?id=$2 [L]
```

This rewrites /foo/bar/ to /foo.php?id=bar